# does heat kill hard drives? hhd lifespan due to heat

Tags: heat, heatsink, power-dissipation, hard-drive

These days it's hard to buy an external 3.5" hard drive with a fan inside or well heat dissipation design. I have 4 of such hard drives, and two  have already failed in first few months. Here is the deal; They all run very hot in few minutes of copying some files. Some show 50 max and some 70 max degree Celsius after power up for a period of time, and I am pretty sure that either the hardware or software have prevented them to show numbers higher than that. so it is safe to say most fan-less external hard drive can reach up to 80 degree and more in 30 minutes of continuous operation. I have actually took apart all four of my external hard drives. Their designs are all similar, plastic case, a very thin metal part links the hard drive, the controller pcb and the plastic case together. Very minimalist design, Seems to me, they are using the hard drive aluminum body as the heatsink, and it is very hot to touch after 30 minutes.

So my questions will be how much of this heat really contributed to my two failed hard drives or for hard drives failure in general? Is the bulky aluminum hard drive body a good heatsink? Why all manufacturers suddenly choose to not include a fan? ( This is like a trend. )

Comment: I do not remember I ever saw HDD with a fan, however was repairing HDDs back those days for several years. What answer you are looking for? Was that a cause? Probably yes. HDDs should be installed into well ventilated chassis. Can you do anything on it other than installing it properly? No.

Comment: Perhaps a bigger issue with hard-drives is that heat causes expansion of the disks themselves. That can mean data written when the hard-drive is hot, may not me readable when the drive cools down. Back in the day when I used to develop the things, that was the biggest roadblock to packing more data onto a drive. The effect is exasperated on drives that have a stack of disks, which is most of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen heat kill plenty of hard drives in poorly-built enclosures in my time. Additionally, temperature is one of the SMART failure criteria.

A hard drive's casing is designed to be sufficient heatsinking *when used in a well-ventilated environment*. A fanless enclosure certainly does not present a well-ventilated environment, and the small amount of air in an enclosure usually acts as an insulator, exacerbating the problem.

If the hard drive is bolted tightly to the outside of the enclosure then the enclosure can act as additional heatsinking, but if the drive is merely slid into grooves in the enclosure, or even worse bolted onto a PCB within the enclosure, then heat can build up and damage can occur.